# php_pthreads.dll - The specified module could not be found.?

Tags: php, xampp, pthreads

Hi I am trying to implement threading in php. What ever I have read till this point I got to know pthreads library can be used for this purpose.

I have gone through the php installation guide below :

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php

After downloading pthreads windows installation zip I unzipped it & placed following files in respective locations :

Move

```
php_pthreads.dll to the 'bin\php\ext\' directory.
      Move pthreadVC2.dll to the 'bin\php\' directory.
      Move pthreadVC2.dll to the 'bin\apache\bin' directory.
      Move pthreadVC2.dll to the 'C:\windows\system32' directory.
```

Configured php\php.ini and add

```
extension=php_pthreads.dll
```

But I am getting an error on server startup which is as follows :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pthreads.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0
```

I am unable to detect what is the issue above file php_pthreads.dll is @given location, what may go wrong.

PHP Version of xampp : 5.6.15, Pthreads lib version : 3.1.0 both the softwares are for x86 architecture.

I made change as suggested by Saitama below, changed version of pthreads from 3.1.0 to 2.0.0 I got new warning as below :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pthreads: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

How to I match these compile API version I have php extension build number as 20131226 but how to decide this number while downloading a pthread binary installation zip ?

Comment: I would recommend you to, if possible build `pthreads` by compiling the source. Or download the pthreads version which matches the the PHP version as yours.

Comment: How do I check compile version of pthreads while downloading I know php compile version ?

Answer (score 2):

The `pthreads` module can only be loaded if you are using the CLI SAPI.

And it is only available under `CLI SAPI` only.

Also, `pthreads v3` is only for PHP7 and since you are using `PHP 5.6` you need to use `pthreads v2`.

It is only available under the cli sapi because, spawning multiple threads under apache can prove to be buggy.

So, the problems are:
 * You are trying to load pthreads under some another SAPI than `CLI`.
 * You need to use `pthreadsv2` rather than `pthreadsv3`.

---

Note: If you would be using `pthreadsv2` you can most probably load pthreads under the apache SAPI. But still it is not recommended.  Using some other approach would be highly recommended.